# MySQL Slow Queries Error: Can't determine basedir from 'my_pri

Tags: mysql, performance

I follow the instructions in this guide:

http://www.ducea.com/2006/11/06/identifying-mysql-slow-queries/

This guide is about how to setup an log for slow queries, in other words, queries with an execution time up to 1 second.

After put hands on I wait few hours and nextly try to get some data, but I only get this error, I try to find solve of this in Google but there is nothing which help me find and solve this issue.

```
root@...... [~]# mysqldumpslow -s c -t 10

Can't determine basedir from 'my_print_defaults mysqld' output: --long_query_time=1

--log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

**Some idea about?** Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this well

```
mysqldumpslow -s c -t 10 /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

Answer (score 1):

vcs is correct.  However, consider that these days the Performance Schema gives much more detailed information:

http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/02/11/performance_schema-vs-slow-query-log/

Answer (score 0):

Add basedir=/var/lib/mysql ...or some dir to your /etc/my.cnf file.  Restart the mysqld service and you should be able to see output from mysqldumpslow.

Comment: i use windows and still got the same message